# thread stack access from callback after exit

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

The following code has a callback registered for some clean-up actions.
As soon as a stop is requested, the callback is invoked from `main` and the thread exits.
The callback then waits a few ms and accesses the `vector` on the thread stack which *seems* invalid since the thread no longer exists.

`valgrind` and `g++ -fsanitize=address` do not report any problem and the output of `size()` is always as expected.
This makes me wonder if it is correct to access the vector on the thread stack as long as `request_stop` in `main` has not returned.

The output is:

```
thread finished 140037635319488
call back from: 140037639857984, size 1234
main finished 140037639857984
```

Note that the vector is accessed *after* the thread has finished its last line.

Question: is this code undefined behavior?

Some relevant quotes from the C++ standard might be helpful

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <stop_token>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void thread_func(std::stop_token st)
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    std::stop_callback cb{st, [&v]
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);
            for (int i=0; i<1234; ++i)
                v.push_back(i);
            std::cout << "call back from: " << std::this_thread::get_id()
                      << ", size " << v.size() << '\n';
        }};

    while (!st.stop_requested())
    {
        // ...
    }
    std::cout << "thread finished " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::stop_source src;
    auto t = src.get_token();

    auto thr = std::jthread{thread_func, t};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);

    bool b = src.request_stop();

    std::cout << "main finished " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the callback is being run from another thread (in your case the main thread in the `request_stop()` call), then the destructor of `std::stop_callback` blocks until that call is finished and destroys the stored callable only afterwards.

Because you declared `v` before `cb`, the vector will be destroyed only after the destructor of `cb` returns during the stack unwinding when `thread_func` returns after the stop request. The thread only exits after the stack unwinding.

Comment: I understand the order of destruction of `v` and `cb`, but that happens long after the thread has reached its last line (cout << thread finished). So what exactly is keeping the thread stack alive after that?

Comment: @Tootsie When the thread function exits its stack is unwound and all destructors of automatic storage duration variables in its scope are called in reverse order, just as for any other function. `cb`'s destructor is specified to block until the callback has been executed. The standard library will implement that e.g. with a mutex. The thread is done only after all of the stack is unwound and all destructors have finished executing.